# Make wget convert links to other pages in input-file

Tags: wget

I'm using wget to archive a discussion from a forum. The discussion is over several pages, navigated to with next and previous buttons.

I generated a list of the page urls and used that for the input-file, however the convert-links option is not converting the next and previous links, only the images.

Is there any way to make it do that?

I could use -r, but that would need a depth of 64 to get the whole discussion, and therefore it would get a whole load of extra unwanted stuff as well.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a workaround. It was easy enough to change the input file to html and upload it.  Then with -r and -l1 it correctly converted the links.